# Unable to create index directory: /mnt/genapp/apps when deploy Spring MVC website

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, cloudbees

I have finished my website using **Spring MVC with Maven**. Now I want to deploy it to **CloudBees** for testing. Every settings(connecting to db, code logic,...) are ok but when I start the application, I'm facing a problem about **indexing in Hibernate Search**. It looks like I don't have permission to **create index directory** in Cloud Bees Tomcat 7 server. Below is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to initialize directory provider: org.appfuse.model.User
at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:87)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:216)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.initialize(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:89)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createDirectoryManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:241)
... 53 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to create index directory: /mnt/genapp/apps/3926c2d0/fsgetter/index for index org.appfuse.model.User
at   org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderHelper.makeSanityCheckedDirectory(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:261)
at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderHelper.getVerifiedIndexDir(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:243)
at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider.initialize(FSDirectoryProvider.java:66)
at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:84)
... 56 more
```

Below is my POJO need to index:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.persistence.Version;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Analyze;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.DocumentId;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.IndexedEmbedded;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
@Indexed
@XmlRootElement
public class User extends BaseObject implements Serializable, UserDetails {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3832626162173359411L;

private Long id;
private String username;                    // required
private String password;                    // required
private String confirmPassword;
private String passwordHint;
private String firstName;                   // required
private String lastName;                    // required
private String email;                       // required; unique
private String phoneNumber;
private String website;
private Address address = new Address();
private Integer version;
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
private boolean enabled;
private boolean accountExpired;
private boolean accountLocked;
private boolean credentialsExpired;
private int freeLink;

/**
 * Default constructor - creates a new instance with no values set.
 */
public User() {
}

/**
 * Create a new instance and set the username.
 *
 * @param username login name for user.
 */
public User(final String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@DocumentId
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Column(nullable = false, length = 50, unique = true)
@Field
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

@Column(nullable = false)
@XmlTransient
@JsonIgnore
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Transient
@XmlTransient
@JsonIgnore
public String getConfirmPassword() {
    return confirmPassword;
}

@Column(name = "password_hint")
@XmlTransient
public String getPasswordHint() {
    return passwordHint;
}

@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 50)
@Field
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

@Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 50)
@Field
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
@Field
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

@Column(name = "phone_number")
@Field(analyze= Analyze.NO)
public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

@Field
public String getWebsite() {
    return website;
}

/**
 * Returns the full name.
 *
 * @return firstName + ' ' + lastName
 */
@Transient
public String getFullName() {
    return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
}

@Embedded
@IndexedEmbedded
public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)    
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
)
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

/**
 * Convert user roles to LabelValue objects for convenience.
 *
 * @return a list of LabelValue objects with role information
 */
@Transient
public List<LabelValue> getRoleList() {
    List<LabelValue> userRoles = new ArrayList<LabelValue>();

    if (this.roles != null) {
        for (Role role : roles) {
            // convert the user's roles to LabelValue Objects
            userRoles.add(new LabelValue(role.getName(), role.getName()));
        }
    }

    return userRoles;
}

/**
 * Adds a role for the user
 *
 * @param role the fully instantiated role
 */
public void addRole(Role role) {
    getRoles().add(role);
}

/**
 * @return GrantedAuthority[] an array of roles.
 * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#getAuthorities()
 */
@Transient
public Set<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new LinkedHashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    authorities.addAll(roles);
    return authorities;
}

@Version
public Integer getVersion() {
    return version;
}

/**
 * @return the freeLink
 */
@Column(name = "freeLink")
public int getFreeLink() {
    return freeLink;
}

@Column(name = "account_enabled")
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

@Column(name = "account_expired", nullable = false)
public boolean isAccountExpired() {
    return accountExpired;
}

/**
 * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#isAccountNonExpired()
 * @return true if account is still active
 */
@Transient
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return !isAccountExpired();
}

@Column(name = "account_locked", nullable = false)
public boolean isAccountLocked() {
    return accountLocked;
}

/**
 * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#isAccountNonLocked()
 * @return false if account is locked
 */
@Transient
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return !isAccountLocked();
}

@Column(name = "credentials_expired", nullable = false)
public boolean isCredentialsExpired() {
    return credentialsExpired;
}

/**
 * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#isCredentialsNonExpired()
 * @return true if credentials haven't expired
 */
@Transient
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return !credentialsExpired;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
    this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
}

public void setPasswordHint(String passwordHint) {
    this.passwordHint = passwordHint;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public void setWebsite(String website) {
    this.website = website;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public void setVersion(Integer version) {
    this.version = version;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public void setAccountExpired(boolean accountExpired) {
    this.accountExpired = accountExpired;
}

public void setAccountLocked(boolean accountLocked) {
    this.accountLocked = accountLocked;
}

public void setCredentialsExpired(boolean credentialsExpired) {
    this.credentialsExpired = credentialsExpired;
}

/**
 * @param freeLink the freeLink to set
 */
public void setFreeLink(int freeLink) {
    this.freeLink = freeLink;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof User)) {
        return false;
    }

    final User user = (User) o;

    return !(username != null ? !username.equals(user.getUsername()) : user.getUsername() != null);

}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public int hashCode() {
    return (username != null ? username.hashCode() : 0);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public String toString() {
    ToStringBuilder sb = new ToStringBuilder(this, ToStringStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE)
            .append("username", this.username)
            .append("enabled", this.enabled)
            .append("accountExpired", this.accountExpired)
            .append("credentialsExpired", this.credentialsExpired)
            .append("accountLocked", this.accountLocked);

    if (roles != null) {
        sb.append("Granted Authorities: ");

        int i = 0;
        for (Role role : roles) {
            if (i > 0) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append(role.toString());
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        sb.append("No Granted Authorities");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}
Update application-context.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true">

    <!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Activates scanning of @Repository and @Service -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.giangnt" />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.search.default.indexBase=fsgetter/index
                hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I want to ask how to create index directory in Cloud Bees tomcat 7 server so that my web application can publish for testing?

Answer (score 0):

Filesystem isn't persistent, so for your safety it's write proteceted but java.io.tmpDir - as you can use this one to store whatever temp file you need, but have to know it will disappear on next deployment / restart

Comment: I didnt get you, Nicolas.You mean I should not use Filesystem in hibernate.search.default.directory_provider ??

Comment: you can use the java temporary folder while the application is running. It will be deleted when your container restart